# Ubuntu 20.04 with ZFS root fails to boot after installing xen

Tags: boot, grub2, zfs, xen, initrd

I did some Google searches but failed to find anything for this problem.
After installing 20.04 using the ZFS root option I installed Xen. When it rebooted it failed in initramfs with the error "No pool imported". I was able to boot the previous kernel. When I examined the /boot/grub/grub.cfg I found what looked like invalid "root=ZFS=" options like this:

"root=ZFS=/ROOT/ubuntu_xxxxxx"

The previous kernel that boots looks like this:

"root=ZFS=rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_xxxxxx"

After looking in /etc/default/grub and /etc/grub.d I was unable to figure out why they were different and how I could change it.

As a test saved a copy and edited /boot/grub/grub.cfg adding the rpool to each "root=ZFS=" line where rpool was missing. This time I was able to boot the Xen kernel.

Questions:

1. How do I fix the grub configuration with "root=ZFS=rpool/" so the normal tools like grub2-mkconfig/update-grub will work?
2. Is this a bug in 20.04, or did I do something wrong like the order I installed packages?

Comment: Have you seen [this issue](https://github.com/openzfs/openzfs-docs/issues/92) on the zfs GitHub repo?